# Can readfile for sending content-disposition head use files outside of the web root?

Tags: php, header, download

If I link someone to a file:

`site.com/file.php?id=someid`

and that gets a url which is in `~/files/somefile.zip` which is outside of the document root, will this work? are there security risks by doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it? That should work fine; php does not care about the document root.

It also gives you more control over when and to whom you serve the file so in a lot of cases it is actually improving the security (if the files are only supposed to be available behind a login for example).